# Why is this View nil in awakeFromNib()?

Tags: swift, awakefromnib

I'm practicing awakeFromNib.

I have a single `UIView` in Main.storyboard.
This UIView inherit `class CardView`.

Codes are below

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var cardView: CardView!

}
```

And I have a `CardView.xib`. In, CardView.xib, there's a default single UIView which inherits a `class CardView`. And inside this UIView, there's the other single view which inherits a `class CardContentView`.
And Of course, I have a CardView.swift which have `class CardView`.

Codes are below

```
class CardView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var cardContentView: CardContentView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        cardContentView.layer.cornerRadius = 16
    }
}
```

And I have a `CardContentView.xib`. In, CardContentView.xib, there's a default single `UIView` which inherits a default `class UIView`.
And Of course, I have a CardContentView.swift which have `class CardContentView`.

Codes are below

```
class CardContentView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var backgroundView: UIView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit(){
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CardContentView", owner: self, options: nil)
        self.addSubview(backgroundView)
    }

}
```

Yes, I want to show the `CardContentView` to `cardView` in ViewController through `class CardView`.

But when I run, the error pops in `class CardView`

The error line is on the `func awakeFromNib`

The specific line is `cardContentView.layer.cornerRadius = 16`.

The error message is `Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. Especially, `cardContentView = nil`.

I don't know why `cardContentView = nil`.

I linked cardContentView in Xib board to `class CardView` in CardView.swift.

And how should I modify the code to run this?

Thank you!

Comment: storyboard does not load xibs.

Comment: @Sulthan Thank you for your comment. You mean that I need to initiate 'var cardView' in ViewController? or something else?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to connect the cardView outlet in the main storyboard, and of course, you've added a view in your ViewController. Then in your CardView class, you have to instantiate cardContentView outlet, because in CardView.xib you do not have any reference to cardContentView. Make sure that you've connected backgroundView outlet in CardContentView.xib.

```
class CardView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var cardContentView: CardContentView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        cardContentView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CardContentView", owner: self, options: nil)!.first as! CardContentView
        self.addSubview(cardContentView)
        cardContentView.layer.cornerRadius = 16

        //you can also get access to the subviews of cardContentView
        //cardContentView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}


class CardContentView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var backgroundView: UIView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = .yellow
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        //commonInit()
    } 

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        //commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I tried based on your advice, but 'this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key backgroundView.' pops.

Comment: @Hoo you can access the subviews of cardContentView in CardView class. I edited the answer, for example, I changed the background color of the backgroundView. Then you don't need to instantiate the backgroundView in the commonInit method of CardContentView.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But, what I want is using pure backgroundView in CardContentView. I want to implement it to CardView nothing Changed.

Comment: @Hoo you can override awakeFromNib method in CardContentView class. without instantiating backgroundView, you can access to it. See the edited answer.