# Why could not cast value of type 'UIView' to other View?

Tags: swift, uiview, casting

This question deals with the same code with my previous question.  
(The previous question is [Why is this View nil in awakeFromNib()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52911734/why-is-this-view-nil-in-awakefromnib))  
But totally different approach.  
It's not the duplicated question.  
So let me restructure my question.

First, let me summarize my project.

Thanks to previous answer, I can reuse xib now. 
This is CardContentView.xib

[image]

Codes are below

```
@IBDesignable class CardContentView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundView: UIView!

    @IBInspectable var nibName:String?
    var contentView: UIView?


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        xibSetup()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        xibSetup()
        contentView?.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    }


    func xibSetup(){
        guard let view = loadViewFromNib() else { return }
        view.frame = self.bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        addSubview(view)
        contentView = view
    }


    func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView? {
        guard let nibName = nibName else { return nil }
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: nibName, bundle: bundle)
        return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView
    }
}
```

And this is CardView.xib, the property follows 'class CardContentView'

[image]

Codes are below

```
class CardView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet weak var cardContentView: CardContentView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        cardContentView.layer.cornerRadius = 16
    }
}
```

This is Main.storyboard. with a single UIView.
[image]

Codes are below

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var cardView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

But, I want to reuse class 'CardView' to 'cardView' property in ViewController.  
I want to get 'background' property to 'cardView' property (In simple words, I want to change the yellow box to the blue box in CardContentView!).  
And I want to make 'cardView' property with a transition effect.  
But, I cannot make extension because it's not in a UIView class, but in a ViewController class.  
So I need to make another UIView class.  
That's why I made a CardView class separately.  
(Of course, I want to organize codes neatly by making another file.)

So, I tried 2 different ways.

1. Set the property 'cardView' class as CardView, and connect it to ViewController.

   ```
   class ViewController: UIViewController {

       @IBOutlet weak var cardView: CardView!

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
       }
   }
   ```
2. Cast 'CardView' class to other property in ViewController

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       let tappedView = self.cardView as! CardView
       self.view.addSubview(tappedView)    
   }
   ```

But both of them make errors.  
1. When I made '@IBOutlet weak var cardView: CardView!', it throws error message, 'Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value, cardContentView = nil'.  
2. When I made 'let tappedView = self.cardView as! CardView', it throws error message, 'Could not cast value of type 'UIView' (0x10a229ff8) to 'AwakeFromNibTutorial.CardView' (0x1060aa8d0).'

How can I solve this problem?  
Please help me!

Answer (score -1):

- In the CardView class's `awakeFromNib()`, you are not calling `super.awakeFromNib()`.
- You would have to use the same logic (`xibSetup()`) that you used to load the **CardContentView** from it's corresponding XIB, to load the **CardView** also from its XIB.
- In the ViewController in your storyboard, have you assigned the class of the **UIView** to **CardView**?

Comment: 1. error still pops with 'super.awakeFromNib()' 2. how? 3. Of course, I assigned it.

Comment: 2. I tried but still throws 'cardContentView = nil' plus, 'contentView = nil'

Comment: For **CardView**, in the IB, you seem to have assigned the class name to the UIView, and not the File's owner. Try updating that too.

Comment: Update for what? In CardView.xib, no File's owner, set default view's class as 'CardView, set UIView class as 'CardContentView'.